# makefile: how to deal with colon in variable

Tags: variables, makefile, substitution

In a **makefile**:

```
a = d:\wuyu
```

My purpose is to get the part before `:`. That's to say, "d" in the example.

Using `b = $(patsubst :%,,$(a))` didn't work. Variable "b" is same to variable "a". Using

```
c = `echo $(a)|sed -e 's/:.*//'`
```

did work. But it resulted in another problem: `*** multiple target patterns.  Stop.` when doing make since there is `:` in the sed command. Adding `\` in sed didn't work.

Therefore, how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patsubst doesn't work because your pattern is `:%` which will only match strings that start with a colon; your string doesn't start with a colon so it doesn't match, so no substitution is performed.

You can do this by splitting the string into multiple words:

```
b = $(firstword $(subst :, ,$(a)))
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work. I don't know the function `firstword`. Now I learn it.

Comment: Gak thanks @warem.  I wish the SO editor had paren matching :-)